# angular: 2 way binding to map via dynamic map key

Tags: angular

using Angular 9, I got a binding issue.
Got a list of input boxes (prod1, prod2,... prodn) which I want to 2-way-bind to the corresponding value in a map/dictionary stored in compnent.ts.
map is defined like this in component.ts

```
x = {"prod1": 0, "prod2": 0}
```

in component html trying to access.
it works when I hardcode binding value:

```
<input matInput type="number" min=0 value="0" size="10" id="{{ product.id }}" [(ngModel)]="amounts.prod1">
```

but what i need is something that let's me pick the key based on input id, so something like this but it is not working:

```
<input matInput type="number" min=0 value="0" size="10" id="{{ product.id }}" [(ngModel)]="{{'amounts.' + product.id}}">
```

How can I pass the key to the map n that binding expression? Thanks!

Comment: the `ngModel` attribute accepts a JavaScript expression, and `o.name` and `o['name']` are the same in JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[(ngModel)]="amounts[product.id]"`.